# Fazer objetos aparecerem

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Eu estou com uma dificuldade em fazer uma caixa de seleção aparecer ou sumir dependendo da opção selecionada.
Eu não entendo praticamente nada de Javascript no momento.

Meu exemplo:

Quero fazer com que apareça uma caixa de texto quando a opção "Outro" estiver ativa, para que o usuário possa informar a situação dele e uma caixa de seleção quando a opção "Maquina" estiver selecionada com as opções de maquinas. Caso nenhuma das duas estejam selecionadas, então não mostrará nada.
   Espero que alguém consiga me ajudar. Grato desde já.

```
<select name="tipobroblema" id="tipoproblema">
    <option value="">- Tipo Problema -</option>
    <option value="maquina">Maquina</option>
    <option value="vazamento">Banheiro</option>
    <option value="arcondicionado">Ar Condicionado</option>
    <option value="outro">Outro</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Se vc fizer com inputs do tipo "Radio Button" da para fazer apenas com CSS, agora se for uma lista do tipo Select acho que só com JS mesmo

Comment: Raul poste o código que já desenvolveu até aqui.

Comment: Eu só estou com o select Leandro.

Comment: Sim, Hugo. Porém preciso fazer com select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Javascript puro** - sem bibliotecas, sem jquery.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");

    var z = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
    
    if (z == "outro") {
    hiddenDiv1.style.display='inline-block';
    } 
    else{
    hiddenDiv1.style.display='none';
    }
    
    if (z == "maquina") {
    hiddenDiv2.style.display='inline-block';
    } 
    else{
    hiddenDiv2.style.display='none';
    }
       
}
```

```css
#hiddenDiv1,#hiddenDiv2  {
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari e Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari e Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}


/* Efeito Place Holder CSS no input */
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {  
  color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

/* Place Holder CSS for Focus */
:hover::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.75;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
:hover:-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.75;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
:hover::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0.75;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
:hover:-ms-input-placeholder {  
  opacity: 0.75;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

/* Place Holder CSS for Focus */
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
:focus:-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {  
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="">- Tipo Problema -</option>
    <option value="maquina">Maquina</option>
    <option value="vazamento">Banheiro</option>
    <option value="arcondicionado">Ar Condicionado</option>
    <option value="outro">Outro</option>
</select>

<div id="hiddenDiv1" style="display:none">
<input type="text" placeholder="Descreva o problema">
</div>

<div id="hiddenDiv2" style="display:none">
<select class="form-control select" name="estado">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option value="1">Maquina 1</option>
    <option value="2">Maquina 2</option>
    <option value="3">Maquina 3</option>
    <option value="4">Maquina 4</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**Descobrindo o valor selecionado**

A variável `x` possui a combobox, então podemos acessar algumas propriedades como, por exemplo, `selectedIndex` que contém um valor inteiro com o índice do item `option` selecionado.

Explicando melhor, cada tag option possui um índice, no seu exemplo temos o seguinte:

```
índice  option
  0     <option value="">- Tipo Problema -</option>
  1     <option value="maquina">Maquina</option>
  2     <option value="vazamento">Banheiro</option>
  3     <option value="arcondicionado">Ar Condicionado</option>
  4     <option value="outro">Outro</option>
```

Quando o usuário clicar em uma opção da combobox, o seguinte código mostrará qual é o índice escolhido:

```
x.selectedIndex
```

cada option possui pelo menos 2 propriedades interessantes: `text` e `value`:

1 -  `text` é a “label”’, o texto entre as tags `<options></options>`.

```
 x.options[x.selectedIndex].text;
```

2 - `value` é a “chave”, o valor da propriedade value.

```
 x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
```

### Outra forma

> Se quiser aplicar os efeitos do exemplo acima basta aplicar o CSS

```js
 function show(aval) {
    if (aval == "outro") {
    hiddenDiv1.style.display='inline-block';
    } 
    else{
    hiddenDiv1.style.display='none';
    }
    
    if (aval == "maquina") {
    hiddenDiv2.style.display='inline-block';
    } 
    else{
    hiddenDiv2.style.display='none';
    }
    
}
```

```html
<select onchange="java_script_:show(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option value="">- Tipo Problema -</option>
    <option value="maquina">Maquina</option>
    <option value="vazamento">Banheiro</option>
    <option value="arcondicionado">Ar Condicionado</option>
    <option value="outro">Outro</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="hiddenDiv1" style="display:none">
<input type="text" placeholder="Descreva o problema">
</div>

<div id="hiddenDiv2" style="display:none">
<select class="form-control select" name="estado">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option value="1">Maquina 1</option>
    <option value="2">Maquina 2</option>
    <option value="3">Maquina 3</option>
    <option value="4">Maquina 4</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado Leo. Teria como eu colocar um efeito de transição quando o objeto aparece? É só uma duvida

Comment: @RaulGermano, basta acrescentar um CSS, editei a resposta colocando um efeito `fadein`

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
    <select name="tipobroblema" id="tipoproblema">
        <option value="">- Tipo Problema -</option>
        <option value="maquina">Maquina</option>
        <option value="vazamento">Banheiro</option>
        <option value="arcondicionado">Ar Condicionado</option>
       <option value="outro">Outro</option>
     </select>

     <div id="maquina">Maquina: <input type="text" name="maquina" /></div>
     <div id="outro" style="display:none;">Outro: <input type="text" name="outro" /></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {

  var maquina = $('#maquina');
  var outro = $('#outro');
  var tipoproblema = $('#tipoproblema');

  maquina.hide();
  outro.hide();

  tipoproblema.on("change", function() {
    maquina.hide();
    outro.hide();

    if(this.value == 'maquina') {
         maquina.show();
      } else if(this.value == 'outro') {
          outro.show();
      }
  });
});
```

Caso não tenha o jquery adicionado ao seu HTML, adicione-o assim:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Veja funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/anndreyy/wbzbgj0z/3/#&togetherjs=CT96Ndf6rC

Answer (score 0):

Vou te mostrar um exemplo simples, para voce se basear e montar o seu codigo, basicamente vc precisa pegar o valor escolhido e verificar e mostrar o input que deseja

```js
$('#tipoproblema').change(function(){
    if(this.value == 'maquina') {
        $('#divMaquina').css('display', '');
        $('#divOutro').css('display', 'none');
    } else if(this.value == 'outro') {
        $('#divMaquina').css('display', 'none');
        $('#divOutro').css('display', '');          
    } else {
        $('#divMaquina').css('display', 'none');
        $('#divOutro').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
<select name="tipobroblema" id="tipoproblema">
    <option value="">- Tipo Problema -</option>
    <option value="maquina">Maquina</option>
    <option value="vazamento">Banheiro</option>
    <option value="arcondicionado">Ar Condicionado</option>
   <option value="outro">Outro</option>
 </select>
<div id="divMaquina" style="display:none;">Maquina: <input type="text" name="maquina" /></div>
<div id="divOutro" style="display:none;">Outro: <input type="text" name="outro" /></div>
```

avisa se deu certo

Comment: Sim ficou muito bom. Eu adaptei ao meu caso aqui. colocando um select no <input> da maquina. Agradeço a ajuda